# posting on facebook user wall from my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website which use facebook connect.
I want that a user can post on his wall when clicking a button.

I add the permission : publish_stream and I was expected that when authenticating to facebook, the facebook dialog will ask for permission to posting on the wall (because I asked for publish_stream) but it does not. so I am getting the dialog only when trying to post on its wall instead of when user is first signed up using facebook connect.

Am I doing somthing wrong ?

Comment: do you want it to behave differently? or what exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to approval to post on the user wall when he first connect. not when trying to post to the wall

Comment: jep, should be [doable](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/). so what's your code?